# How to manually set the Firestore document ID saving a new document calling Firestore API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

I am finding the following problem trying to save a new document into Firestore database by calling the related POST API and manually setting the document ID.

I am using Python but I suppose that the problem is not related to the language.

I try to explain what I have done and what is not working. My first attempt (that works but automatically set the document ID on Firestore) was:

First of all, I created this JSON document that will be the payload of my API:

```
# Convert the record to a dictionary
doc = {
    'fields': {
        'surname': {'stringValue':record[2]},
        'firstName': {'stringValue':record[1]},
        'socialSecurityCode': {'stringValue':codici_fiscali_list_as_string},
        'city': {'stringValue':record[4]},
        'personalPhone': {'stringValue':record[5]},
        'personalPhone2': {'stringValue':record[6]},
        'personalEmail': {'stringValue':emails_list_as_string},
        'pazPres': {'stringValue':record[7]},
        'pazNotes': {'stringValue':record[8]},
        'pazMemo': {'stringValue':record[9]},
        'isArchived': {'booleanValue':isArchived},
        'isMigrated': {'booleanValue':True},
        #'decomposition_keyword_search_list':{'arrayValue':{'values':decomposition_keyword_search_list}}
        "decomposition_keyword_search_list":{
         "arrayValue":{
            "values":[
            ]
         }
      }
    }    
}
```

then I perform the API call by these lines:

```
api_endpoint = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY-PROJECT-NAME/databases/(default)/documents/test/'

response = requests.post(api_endpoint, json=doc)
```

It works fine and it put the expected document into my **test** collection. But in this way, the ID was automatically generated by Firestore. For some reason, I have to use the content of a variable as ID (my ID must be the value of my **record[0]** that is a unique string)

So I tried to change the previous API endpoint in the following way:

```
api_endpoint = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY-PROJECT-NAME/databases/(default)/documents/test/'+ record[0]
```

I expected that it creates a document using the **record[0]** as a document ID but it seems that I am wrong since I am obtaining the following error message:

```
Error saving document: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Document parent name \"projects/MY-PROJECT-NAME/databases/(default)/documents/test\" lacks \"/\" at index 71.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

So, what is wrong? What am I missing? How can correctly manually set the ID of the document that I am creating calling the previous API?

Comment: Why don't you use the client libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation for creating documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument).  If you want to specify a document ID, it says you should pass that as a [query parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument#query-parameters) called `documentId`:

> The client-assigned document ID to use for this document.
>
> Optional. If not specified, an ID will be assigned by the service.